# Power from human vs solar radio waves

Tags: radio-frequency

I'm looking for a nicely presented comparison of solar radio waves and human-generated radio waves. The parameter I am most interested in is power. I imagine that human-generated radio waves exceed solar radio waves for the very narrow bands that are commonly transmitted - otherwise it would be difficult to receive them over what is essentially background noise. But I expect that the integrated power of solar radio wave radiation is much higher, except perhaps in bands where it is strongly attenuated by the atmosphere. On the other hand, my expectations might be completely wrong.

Since the human-generated radio waves probably vary strongly with time and location (following a $\frac{1}{r^2}$ law), it may be difficult to get accurate measurements. In that case, I will assume that they are in compliance with regulations e.g. "The FCC limit for public exposure from cellular telephones is an SAR level of 1.6 watts per kilogram (1.6 W/kg)."

Most diagrams of solar power are around the visible range, and in units of ($W/m^{2}/Hz$), which I find difficult to compare to SAR levels. I know the total solar power is a bit more than $1kW/m^2$, but I'm specifically interested in radio waves. The information (no graphs, unfortunately) I found on solar radio flux were in units of $1$SFU $= 10^{-22}W/m^2/Hz$, which seems... small.